# Which Locations (Drives or folders) Should Not be added in windows search indexing?

Tags: windows, search, windows-search

I am face problem in windows search index. if I added whole drive "C:" in indexing, indexing not completed, & take long for get result of search. I am afraid & have doubt that all location should not be added in windows search indexing. particularly the drive, where operating system (OS) installed.

I must be formatting my partition /volume of hard drive (where O/s. Installed) about 2 to 3 times within 6 months just because indexing crashed & if try to repair with FSC or "CHKDSK" that leads fully format hard drive instead of repair or rebuild. I know this problem faced by many users & they already know / believe deeply in their mind that indexing problem leads to fully format drive.

So Which Locations Should Not be added with root in windows search indexing? because if we added whole "C:" drive in locations, indexed database itself collected by indexing also counted as indexable item. so that look as circular -infinite looping start is that true? or if added, which is effect on indexing?

Can anyone guide about that indexing can be corrupt or damage if whole "C:" drive as location added to the indexing?  in short which locations should not add as index location? Why?

Hope there are some ***"Must be known key factors about indexing for longer running your O/s without format your partition/volume or finally whole Drive just for indexing problem"*** may be found there.

Regards,
Chirag Raval.

Comment: Are you only interested in finding files by name (not content)?

Comment: If you find the built-in search troublesome or need more easily-accessible extra parameters, there are third-party search tools available. For example, [The 17 Best Free Search Tools for Windows 10](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-best-free-search-tools-windows-10/) lists some. (I have no connection to that site, I just found it by searching for "file search utility windows 10".)

Comment: @harrymc Content indexing is main core facility & strength of Windows search , just filename not help us what are we looking for

Comment: @AndrewMorton , I don't  hard complain & fully oppose to whole windows search, just want to know strait forward setup. I also tried all 3rd party's, & they are good for their perticular unique requirement. But  I believe, netive is best & as part of O/s. like birth bone, always with you , work stand alone.

Comment: I showed content settings in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to index your whole drive. There is nothing (to me) useful in Program Files and the Windows folder for example.

> indexing crashed & if try to repair with FSC or "CHKDSK" that leads
> fully format hard drive instead of repair or rebuild.

Limit your indexing to prevent this. Indexing on my own machines does not crash after years of use.

The Default Index locations is reasonable as a starting point:  OneNote and Outlook for example from Office.  "Users" include your Documents, Email OST or PST files and like and it is important to include "Users".

I organize well, so I keep a big folder of Application download and I index that.

Here is a good layout for Indexing and as you can see Indexing is complete. This will find file names (and content if content has been enabled.  See below.)

[image: Index Locations]

.

Also make sure Text, Docs, Adobe, and Excel extensions are indexed for content. Content settings provides both filename and content match when searching.
.

[image: Content indexing]

.

Simplify your Indexing to include what you need (as in the examples I provided).

Do not index your whole drive (not needed, and not a good idea).

**After you have changed and saved locations and content indexing, save, restart and re-index.  Allow to run overnight.**

Comment: Thanks for your effort & invaluable strait forward guideline I appreciate.

Comment: Mr John's  @john answer is acceptable & i agree as best answer , I already comment above for them (below to Mr John's answer) I pressed Green Tick Mark button as an acceptance. Thank you All of you, & Mr John.